# Adding Custom Field to Contact Membership Tab

Tags: civimember, contacts, custom-fields

CiviCRM 4.7.9

I have a custom field that I created for memberships. I would like to have this field displayed as a column within the membership tab when viewing a contact.

I've been digging into the tpl/php files and trying to pin down how to do this, but I keep getting lost.

Can anyone help give me some direction for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you might want to update your question with the version of Civi you're using... that might help people assist you a little more easily.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The template you're looking for is templates/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.tpl.  The "browse" action is number 16, and takes up the vast majority of the template, starting around [line 33](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.tpl#L33).

You'll want to populate the `$activeMembers` and/or `$inActiveMembers` array with modified data.  Those are defined in [CRM_Member_Page_Tab](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.php#L211) around line 211, but most likely you'll want to modify the `$membership` array that they're both based on.  The `browse()` method of that function is mostly a "while" loop devoted to building the $membership array, but is sadly devoid of hooks.

Comment: Where do you think would be the best place to modify that array so that it won't interfere with updates? I know I can create a template override file. Is there a good way to modify it from the TPL? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use `hook_civicrm_pageRun` to modify the array.  To modify the template, there's no great option, though both `hook_civicrm_alterTemplateFile` and `hook_civicrm_alterContent` offer a solution.  The community-oriented solution would be to rewrite this page to use the core search, which would let you use `hook_civicrm_searchColumns` after all.  Not sure how much work that would be though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using hook_civicrm_searchColumns

More information about the hook in this page: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_searchColumns

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am unable to get it to modify anything for the membership tab. I am able to get it working with the contribution and pledge tabs though.

Comment: I have verified that it does NOT work for the membership tab. Please see the comment here: https://civicrm.org/blog/lobo/introducing-hookcivicrmsearchcolumns-modify-search-results-meet-your-needs

Comment: `hook_civicrm_searchColumns` works on searches, not the tabs.  The contribution tab happens to use the search functionality to generate the data; memberships doesn't.